# pass multiple query string values in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, routes

There is a below route in Routeconfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "WithParams",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{langue}/{AffID} ",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", AffId = "", langue = "" }
            );
```

I am trying to call this route from some part of  the system.

```
Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("WithParams", new RouteValueDictionary { AffId :123,langue:"EN" });
```

It is giving syntax error,how can we pass query string parameters in the above redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToRoutePermanent("WithParams", new { AffId = 123, langue = "EN" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("AffId", "58");
        dictionary.Add("langue", "EN");


        Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("WithParams", new RouteValueDictionary(dictionary));
```